# Phasing antenna elements using active filters

Tags: antenna, active-filter

I've spent a lot of time looking at the turnstile antenna.  To get that nice round pattern the two elements are 90 degrees out of phase with each other.  This is often achieved using phasing lines.  But I've wondered for awhile if the same could be achieved using active LC filters for RX only.

One element on a third order highpass Chebyshev tuned for the 90 degree phase shift pretty much in the middle of the intended RX range.

The other on a 2nd order bandpass Chebyshev tuned for the 0 degree phase shift in the middle of the RX range.

Filters could be tuned to the intended band (rejecting neighboring stuff) and the amp could live in the antenna, both seem like solid pros from a noise perspective.

So why have I not seen this done?  Is it too touchy in practice?  Or is it done and I just haven't run across it?

Comment: It sounds tome like it might work. Maybe it hasn't been done because it is not the easiest way to do it, though. Maybe a quadrature mixer is easier.

Comment: For a manufacturer, tuning filters is expensive. Far more attractive for them is cutting phasing lines to a specific length, or cutting antenna element lengths or separations to length. For one-off antenna builds (home constructors) the test/measuring equipment to do it right is the expensive part.

Answer (score 0):

> But I've wondered for awhile if the same could be achieved using active LC filters for RX only.

Sure; but I'd caution that it might not be a pure LC filter. Depending on your actual frequency range and powers, there's many ways to implement filters, and the one feasible for your application might not be an LC filter.

Active filters are actually pretty uncommon for RF – at least in the sense of things we usually call "active filter". Building active electronics that are selective but don't have terrible sideeffects (nonlinearity) is a cost- and power-intense problem, and comes with a noise figure. The usual filters that you build if you need a sharp filter are typically either finely-tuned ladder passive filters (most commonly found in sub-microwave frequency), cavity filters (commonly found in things like satellite receivers) and Surface Acoustic Wave (SAW) filters (often in low-cost, and/or highly integrated circuitry), often directly before a Low-Noise Amplifier (LNA).

Turnstiles are typical designs for UHF, i.e. between 300 and 3000 MHz, for lower frequencies they get uncomfortably large (unless you have TV tower style budget) and usually are suboptimal due to mechanical reasons; for RX at lower frequencies, there's often not much reason to use a turnstile. So, assuming UHF, this would put your typical filter design in the realm of SAW filters. These are excellent – but you can't buy a 90°-shifting version of the same SAW filter. Some, often sensitive RX applications with blocking strong transmitters in adjacent bands, also go for cavity filtering in these bands (typical example: weak satellite downlinks with some broadcast, or even worse, active amateur radio bands that spill left and right); you can certainly add enough cavities to achieve a desired multiple of 90° of shift, but that would probably more work than adding 90° worth of transmission line.

> So why have I not seen this done? Is it too touchy in practice? Or is it done and I just haven't run across it?

Note that if you grab your Smith chart, a 90° phase shift doesn't actually need two components, so that's a hint that your approach isn't the wisest!

Sure, an LC filter could maintain transmission line matching. But it would inevitably be lossy, so now you have two different amplitudes that you need to re-normalize to be able to combine the two signals.

Another problem is that of bandwidth: any useful filter, i.e., one that will have its cutoff frequencies not many bandwidths away from the band edges of the signal you care about, will have a non-constant phase in its passband, so any signal that's not a pure tone will be delayed by different phases for different frequency components within its bandwidth.

#### Alternatives

An easy way around this would be if you actually used the fact that you're using a mixer to get the RF signals down to a frequency where you'd want to deal with them (either an IF, or in IQ baseband).

Now, if you mix the signal from one element with your local oscillator (whose phase we can just arbitrarily define to be our reference phase at 0°), and mix the other with a 90° shifted version of that LO, you get the result you need: two IF or baseband signals, 90° out of phase, which you can combine to get the antenna characteristic you need. It's relatively easy to produce a 90° shifted oscillator from a primary oscillator – build a PLL that makes sure the phase delay of the second filter is adjusted such that the two oscillations are orthogonal.

(In the case of using a quadrature mixer, which internally already has a 0° and a 90° shifted LO for I and Q, respectively, you can just use the 90° shifted version from the Q as the I-oscillator for a second mixer, and an inverted (=180°) version of the original LO as the Q-oscillator for the second mixer.)